# Prevent element from being added based on boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean, push

I have an array of ID's ("world") to iterate. If the world element value exists as myArray[n].id then I want to delete the entire element in myArray. If not, then I want to add it to myArray.

```
world = ["12424126","12461667","12492468","12761163"]

myArray = [
{"id": "12424126"},
{"id": "12761163"},
{"id": "12492468"}
]
```

Example: if the first element in world[n] ("12424126") exists in myArray as {"id": "12424126"} then delete the element {"id": "12424126"}

if the first element in world[n] ("12424126") does not exists in myArray, then

```
myArray.push ({"id":world[n]}); 
}

for (n = 0; n <= world.length; n++) { 
ID = world[n]; 

finished = false;

if (myArray.find(x => x.id === ID)) {
var index = _.findIndex(myArray, { "id": ID });
if (index > -1) { myArray.splice(index, 1);
finished = true;}
}

if (!finished) // PROBLEM: THE RECORD IS ADDED REGARDLESS OF FINISHED T/F
{myArray.push ({id:ID }); // HOW CAN I FIX THIS ?
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works as you want

```
world = ["12424126", "12461667", "12492468", "12761163"];

myArray = [{ id: "12424126" }, { id: "12761163" }, { id: "12492468" }];
for (n = 0; n < world.length; n++) {
  ID = world[n];

  var index = myArray.findIndex((item) => item.id == ID);
  if (index > -1) {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    myArray.push({ id: ID });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad to use this versitile and concise code. It works perfectly and I appreciate your contribution to my web app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop will make `finished` turn from true to false again in a next iteration of the loop. You would need to exit the loop immediately when `finished` is set to true.

However, this can be better solved with a `Set`:

```js
const world = ["12424126","12461667","12492468","12761163"];
let myArray = [{"id": "12424126"},{"id": "12761163"},{"id": "12492468"}];

const set = new Set(myArray.map(({id}) => id).concat(world));
myArray = Array.from(set, id => ({id}));

console.log(myArray);
```

If you don't want to *assign* to `myArray` a new array, and not create new objects for those that already existed in the array, then:

```js
const world = ["12424126","12461667","12492468","12761163"];
let myArray = [{"id": "12424126"},{"id": "12761163"},{"id": "12492468"}];

const set = new Set(myArray.map(({id}) => id).concat(world));
myArray.push(...Array.from(set).slice(myArray.length).map(id => ({id})));

console.log(myArray);
```

This second solution assumes however that `myArray` did not already have duplicate id values.